# The XML for Analysis request timed out before it was completed. Timeout value: 300 sec

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

We have SQL Server and Analysis Services 2016. When I try to deploy the Tabular model I keep getting the following error:

```
The XML for Analysis request timed out before it was completed. Timeout value: 300 sec.

The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed.

The XML for Analysis request timed out before it was completed. Timeout value: 300 sec.

The XML for Analysis request timed out before it was completed. Timeout value: 300 sec.

'.
```

I increased ExternalCommandTimeout  and Query Timeout and keep getting the same error.
Any ideas where exactly I can change the Timeout value of 300?

Answer (score 0):

I would put this as a comment, but want to share pictures.

Has this ever worked from this computer? What version of Visual Studio are you using?

I would suggest using VS 2022 with the latest Extension:
[image]

Double check your settings under **Project > Properties...**
[image]

Sometimes these settings get changed and you aren't connecting to the correct server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. it never worked from this computer. The visual studion version is 17.8.5. The vrsion of Analysis Services is 3.0.15, the latest one. I found a workaround, I deploy the meta data only and once deployed I refresh the model